# Create xml file with existing Folder and File names through shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm very new to Shell Script. I need to create an XML file with Folder and files within the folder. The requirement is something like below.

For example: I have a folder called 'classes'
under this folder I have multiple files like '1.cls', '2.cls', '3.cls', etc.,

Similarly, I have other folders as well.
For example:
Folder name - 'Pages'
Files Under that folder name - '1.page', '2.page', '3.page' etc.,

Now my XML file should look something like below:

```xml
<types>
    <members>1</members>
    <members>2</members>
    <members>3</members>
    <name>classes</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>1</members>
    <members>2</members>
    <members>3</members>
    <name>Pages</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Why? Where is the folder structure coming from? What have you tried?

Comment: @GemTaylor 
Why? - I'm trying to set up continuous integration for my project.  
Where is the folder structure coming from? - These folders are available in Git branch from there I wanted to create an XML file in runtime with Shell Script.  
What have you tried? - I was able to create filenames or folder names into a text file but that's not exactly I wanted.

Comment: So your use of simple echo commands isn't producing the output you want? Show us those echo commands and we show you how to fix them. That's the way it works. Oh and pleasze edit the extra information into the question...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the directory where other required directories and their files are present:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -r XML_FILE="Sample.xml"

[ -f ${XML_FILE} ] && : > ${XML_FILE}

for directory_name in $(ls -F . | grep '/' | sed 's|/||')
do
   echo -e "<types>" >> ${XML_FILE}
   dirfiles=$(ls -A ${directory_name})
   if [ "${dirfiles}" ] ; then
      for files in ${dirfiles}
      do
         echo -e "\t<members>${files/.*}</members>" >> ${XML_FILE}
      done
   fi
   echo -e "\t<name>${directory_name}</name>" >> ${XML_FILE}
   echo -e "</types>" >> ${XML_FILE}
done
```

**Example**

*As per your example statements*

```
mkdir -p classes Pages
touch classes/{1.cls,2.cls,3.cls}
touch Pages/{1.page,2.page,3.page}
```

Let the script be `xmls.sh`.

Execute the script: `bash xmls.sh`

View the output of `Sample.xml`: `cat Sample.xml`

```
<types>
    <members>1</members>
    <members>2</members>
    <members>3</members>
    <name>classes</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>1</members>
    <members>2</members>
    <members>3</members>
    <name>Pages</name>
</types>
```

Now, `Sample.xml` file contains the above XML elements.